# Redirect requested asp urls to php using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2.2

We had a major site rework and now our new site is PHP based.  We have some sites which have our old pages linked to them which were asp pages in the past.  I want to create a htaccess rule but I have failed to get the desired result.  If anyone can help it would be great.

The incoming pages will be in the format

http://www.mysite.com/tour.asp?id=1234

where *1234* is dynamic and can vary.  I want to redirect this to the page `viewer.php` and change the query string variable `id` to `tourid` so the page requested should be

http://www.mysite.com/viewer/1234

I have another  rule in htaccess which routs the above url to

http://www.mysite.com/viewer.php?tourid=1234 *(this is working)*

I need a rule by which the 1st url is routed to the 2nd one hoping it will open the 3rd url. How can i achieve this?

Since I am new to htaccess, can someone help me around how to achieve this routing?  I want to clear here that the server now is php and I have to accomplish this using htaccess only.  I followed other similar questions but found none that answers my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPADTE** - I got it wrong first time, here's the corrected version.

```
# Match and capture the id value from the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
# Redirect by passing the ID to the new site - the ? at the end removes existing query string
RewriteRule tour.asp http://www.mysite.com/viewer/%1? [R=301,L]
```

I've assumed the IDs are numeric only.

*The source for this answer is at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html - search for "Modifying the Query String" to find the info about removing the query string.*

Comment: Hi thanks it works with a minor problem it adds the query string at the end like http://www.mysite.com/viewer/324?id=324

Comment: Try adding a ? just after the %1 - I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm... Though irrelevant to the question asked here these rules will apply to all the requests with the querystring id? If yes any way I can restrict that to those only on tour.asp?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs The RewriteRule will only redirect requests that match `tour.asp`, and the RewriteCond just before it makes sure that requests have the `id` query string too

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks for the help.  Accepted and upvoted. Specially for the querystring removal that was gr8